# Using Sass toolkit with Ember

Tags: ember.js, sass, bower, broccolijs

I'm trying to use this [Sass toolkit](https://github.com/at-import/toolkit) with Ember.
I have Sass installed using [Ember-cli-sass](https://github.com/aexmachina/ember-cli-sass)

I have a working app.scss file that's being imported.

> bower install sass-toolkit --save-dev

However when I then try to include any of the mixins they're not found:

```
@include clearfix('false');
```

results in :

The Broccoli Plugin: [SassCompiler] failed with:
Error: no mixin named clearfix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is correct - your SCSS is invalid.

You can't use a mixin before you define it.

When using the Sass-toolkit you need to import it in the head of your sass file:

```
@import "toolkit";
```

Comment: Thanks that makes sense.  Using that however I'm getting 'Error: File to import not found or unreadable: toolkit.'

Comment: @ChrisNevill you need to add it to includePaths as well. See [docs](https://github.com/aexmachina/ember-cli-sass#example)

Comment: Amazing thanks!  I was getting slightly lost in a fog of new stuff there :)